# What is the right design choice here?

Tags: haskell

I'm constructing a `[CalendarDay]` which looks like this

```
newtype CalendarDay = MKCal (Either AvailableDay UnAvailableDay) deriving Show
```

Right now, I am passing an intermediate data type through several filters with the intent
of constructing the `[CalendarDay]` once all information has been gathered. The problem is, the tuple now has become a four-value tuple. Which means it's time to do something different.

My options appear to be one of two.

1) Construct a record holding the four values, passing that along to each filter, then construct the `[CalendarDay]`.

2) Construct the [CalendarDay] as I go along through each filter, dispensing with the intermediate data type altogether.

Opinions welcome. I'm leaning towards option 2.

I'm going to write this up in a [blog](http://www.yesodweb.com/edit/home/30/yesod_diaries/Blog/When_Requirements_Change.markdown) entry. Don't have a blog, but Michael Snoyman's site will serve until I fix that problem.

Comment: Do you mean to be using the list notation here in `[CalendarDay]`? If so, what sort of list are you trying to build? Also, what sort of values are being filtered to build the desired result? It's hard to say much more about the design without a better idea of what needs to happen.

Comment: I was in the middle of elaborating on the problem, when it dawned on me that I could simplify in such a way that will allow me to keep my triple-value tuple and retain the gist of my original design. If I get stuck again I'll further elaborate, but this may be solved.

Comment: It sounds like you learned something along the way, so it would be a good contribution to the community to answer your own question :)

Comment: My concept was wrong, therefore the question is moot. But I could write something up about this experience. I was happy with the way things were, but then my boss changed the requirements. This led to my re-design problem. Sounds like a blog entry, "When Requirements Change."

Comment: The short answer is I will be constructing the [CalendarDay] from the start, not the end.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but there is no value in newtype wrapping an `Either` - just use a plain algebraic type with two cases instead then you can have descriptive naming.

Comment: @stephen. I may be wrong in my design choice, but I disagree with your assertion that there's no value in wrapping an Either in a Newtype. Isn't that what what ErrorT does? What I've left out is the definitions of AvailableDay and UnavailableDay. When this is out of beta I'm going to re-evaluate my choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try building up the type incrementally, replacing `undefined` values with their found value as it is discovered.

If relying on laziness is unappealing, you could guarantee safety by well-defined intermediate types for each stage.